# C# implicitly cast a method to a custom type

Tags: c#, casting, delegates, implicit

I'd like to be able to cast methods implicitly to my own defined type.

Take the following code (I've omitted a bunch of irrelevant code):

```
public abstract class Callback_Base
{
    // Omitted code.
}

public abstract class VoidCallback : Callback_Base
{
    // Omitted code.

    public delegate void Signature();
    public abstract void Run();

    public static implicit operator VoidCallback(Signature callback) { return new BindableVoidCallback(callback); }
}

public class BindableVoidCallback : VoidCallback
{
    protected Signature m_Callback;

    public BindableVoidCallback() : this(null) {}
    public BindableVoidCallback(Signature callback)
    {
        m_Callback = callback;
    }

    public override void Run() { InvokeSafe(); }

    public bool IsBound() { return m_Callback != null; }
    public void Invoke() { m_Callback(); }
    public void InvokeSafe()
    {
        if (IsBound())
            Invoke();
    }

    // Omitted code.
}
```

And then, I'd like all of the following to work.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private void Main()
    {
        // Works
        Action a = Main;
        VoidCallback.Signature s = Main;
        VoidCallback cb0 = s;
        VoidCallback cb1 = (VoidCallback)Main;
        Do(Main);
        DoCb(s);

        // Doesn't work, but would like to work (resolves properly to the implicit operator but doesn't compile).
        VoidCallback cb2 = Main;
        // Doesn't work either.
        s = (VoidCallback.Signature)a;
    }

    private void Do(VoidCallback.Signature test)
    {

    }
    private void DoCb(VoidCallback test)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm a little bit dumbfounded on why Do(Main) compiles with VoidCallback.Signature, but the implicit conversion operator won't work with the same method.

Comment: interesting finding

Comment: `VoidCallback cb2 = new VoidCallback.Signature(Main);` also works

Comment: also C# already has a delegate type defined that is exactly the same as your signature it's called `System.Action`

Comment: You can simplify your question to asking why this doesn't work: `delegate void Signature(); ... Action a = null; Signature s = a;`

Comment: "but doesn't compile" : always include full error messages.

Comment: `error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Main' to non-delegate type 'VoidCallback'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: This is a duplicate question. The issue is that you cannot assign one delegate to another, even if they have the same signature.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, no I didn't intend to call the method, but rather store it.
While the delegate conversion issue answers the last line of the question, it doesn't answer why this works:
Do(Main);
but not this:
VoidCallback cb2 = Main;